# Como remover as linhas duplicadas em um pandas dataframe com chunksize definido?

Tags: python, pandas

Dado que há um dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]})
df.to_csv("tmp.csv", sep="|", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", sep="|", chunksize=3)
```

Como posso remover todas as linhas duplicadas? Mesmo em chunk diferentes.
Isso é, se no primeiro chunk uma linha *1, 1*, então os demais chunk não podem ter.

Comment: Você consegue carregar **todo** o DF na memória contendo apenas as COLUNAS que você quer verificar duplicados? Ou a verificação é de duplicados considera **todas** as colunas e com isso não dá para carregar tudo?

Comment: @PauloMarques , o data frame só tem duas colunas, no caso normal seria um *drop_duplicates* sem *subset*, mas é muito longo.

Comment: A questão pode ser solucionada com o SQLite ou Dask?

Comment: @MárcioMocellin, digamos que o original possua 50 colunas, mas para "checar duplicados" vc só precise de duas delas. Daria para criar uma lista de índice de duplicados carregando apenas as duas colunas e depois criar um iterator para não trazer tais linhas do arquivo.

Comment: Marcio, conseguiu testar minha resposta?